# How to give width to the TabViewItem in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

[image]

I want to implement sometthing like above where the camera tab has the smaller width compare to the others tab in TabView.

I did three tabs with same size but I don't know how to add one more tab but with smaller width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to update the width of native view that contains the camera within the tab layout. The code below lets the layout take only the width it requires to show the content within.

```
const view = nativeTabView.getChildAt(i),
                layoutParams = view.getLayoutParams();

            layoutParams.weight = 0;
            layoutParams.width = android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=93V4yq)

The above example is written in NativeScript Core / TypeScript, there is nothing you have to specifically if you are implementing this on Vue / Angular, just use the appropriate event binding syntax, you should be good.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Manoj. Would like to know how can I take a look of each property and methods that I can access on any nativescript UI widgets b'coz I went through all the properties and methods defined on this api-reference site https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_ui_tab_view_.tabview but could not found anything like getChildAt() method OR wrapContent properties for TabView Class.

Comment: Just looked at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html site and also found the getChildAt() method but still could not see wrapContent property anywhere. I'm very curious to know how I can go through complete docs and try my best to find the solution by myself.

Comment: [getChildAt()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup) is a native android method, so you should look at official android docs. {N} docs will possibly cover only their framework apis.

Comment: `wrapContent` is a hack I do, try to find which tabs I want to `wrapContent` at runtime rather hardcoding a particular index.